# Google App Engine - Frequently getting logged out of the deployed .NET application

Tags: google-app-engine, .net-core, .net-5

Frequently getting logged out from the deployed application, session is not working/timing out too soon in the deployed .net 5 application in the App Engine flex.

Below are the warning logs which i'm getting, not sure are they related to session issue or not.

[Logged warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVyCc.png)

Are there any session settings which needs to be done within GCP console which i'm unaware of?
I've found similar configuration for Java applications but nothing for .NET.

Reference:- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?csw=1#Java_appengine_web_xml_Enabling_sessions

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I found the issue and fixed it as mentioned below

app.yml file is to be modified with custom env instead of the default which Google App Engine flex provides with 2 instances, like below -
Modified app.yml -

```
runtime: custom
```

env: flex
manual_scaling:
instances: 1
resources:
cpu: 1
memory_gb: 0.5
disk_size_gb: 10

Here we are explicitly mentioning the instances and power required to run our app.

The default deployment uses multiple instances, and the sessions seem to be stored privately per instance. If you reload the page a few times, you will see your session exists sometimes and does not exist other times as you toggle between instances.

Hence by providing 1 instance we are restricting our session to be then and there hence resolving the above issue with it.